# How add value to the last values of each categry in R?

Tags: r, dplyr

Sample of data.

```
mydat=structure(list(supplier = c("MyAgent", "MyAgent", "MyAgent", 
"MyAgent", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "S7", "Travelfusion", "Travelfusion", 
"Travelfusion"), date = c("28.03.2021", "28.03.2021", "28.03.2021", 
"28.03.2021", "25.03.2021", "25.03.2021", "25.03.2021", "25.03.2021", 
"25.03.2021", "28.03.2021", "28.03.2021", "28.03.2021"), hour = c(3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 5L, 6L), weekday = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L), base_price = c(1944.7, 
1949.43, 1954.16, 1958.89, 4595.2, 3170.02, 1744.84, 319.65, 
-1105.53, 3.83, 3.49, 3.15)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

How for each category of `supplier` variable, add `100,000` to the most recent value of each category.
For examlple last value of `S7` category =  -1105,53. So `-1105,53+100 000=98894,47` So `98894,47` must be paste as last value.
But to last value of `Travelfusion` category must be add value 200 000.
So desired output

```
       supplier       date hour weekday base_price
1       MyAgent 28.03.2021    3       0    1944.70
2       MyAgent 28.03.2021    4       0    1949.43
3       MyAgent 28.03.2021    5       0    1954.16
4       MyAgent 28.03.2021    6       0  101958.89
5            S7 25.03.2021    7       4    4595.20
6            S7 25.03.2021    8       4    3170.02
7            S7 25.03.2021    9       4    1744.84
8            S7 25.03.2021   10       4     319.65
9            S7 25.03.2021   11       4   98894.47
10 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    4       0       3.83
11 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    5       0       3.49
12 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    6       0  200003.15
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a new column in the data to add the value and use it with `replace` :

```
library(dplyr)

value_to_add <- c(100000,100000, 200000)

mydat %>%
  mutate(value_to_add = value_to_add[match(supplier, unique(supplier))]) %>%
  group_by(supplier) %>%
  mutate(base_price = replace(base_price, n(), last(base_price) + last(value_to_add))) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-value_to_add)

# A tibble: 12 x 5
#   supplier     date        hour weekday base_price
#   <chr>        <chr>      <int>   <int>      <dbl>
# 1 MyAgent      28.03.2021     3       0    1945.  
# 2 MyAgent      28.03.2021     4       0    1949.  
# 3 MyAgent      28.03.2021     5       0    1954.  
# 4 MyAgent      28.03.2021     6       0  101959.  
# 5 S7           25.03.2021     7       4    4595.  
# 6 S7           25.03.2021     8       4    3170.  
# 7 S7           25.03.2021     9       4    1745.  
# 8 S7           25.03.2021    10       4     320.  
# 9 S7           25.03.2021    11       4   98894.  
#10 Travelfusion 28.03.2021     4       0       3.83
#11 Travelfusion 28.03.2021     5       0       3.49
#12 Travelfusion 28.03.2021     6       0  200003.
```

Answer (score 3):

We could do this easily in `base R`.  Create two logical vectors - 1) that returns TRUE for last element of each 'supplier' (i1), 2) where the supplier is 'Travelfusion'.  Use that index to replace the 'base_price' column value

```
i1 <- !duplicated(mydat$supplier, fromLast = TRUE)
i2 <- mydat$supplier == 'Travelfusion'
mydat$base_price[i1 & i2] <- mydat$base_price[i1 & i2] + 200000
mydat$base_price[i1 & !i2] <- mydat$base_price[i1 & !i2] + 100000
```

-output

```
mydat
#       supplier       date hour weekday base_price
#1       MyAgent 28.03.2021    3       0    1944.70
#2       MyAgent 28.03.2021    4       0    1949.43
#3       MyAgent 28.03.2021    5       0    1954.16
#4       MyAgent 28.03.2021    6       0  101958.89
#5            S7 25.03.2021    7       4    4595.20
#6            S7 25.03.2021    8       4    3170.02
#7            S7 25.03.2021    9       4    1744.84
#8            S7 25.03.2021   10       4     319.65
#9            S7 25.03.2021   11       4   98894.47
#10 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    4       0       3.83
#11 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    5       0       3.49
#12 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    6       0  200003.15
```

---

Or using the same logic in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
mydat %>%
   mutate(i1 =!duplicated(supplier, fromLast = TRUE),
       i2 = supplier == 'Travelfusion',
       base_price = case_when(i1 & i2 ~ base_price + 200000,
        i1 & !i2 ~ base_price + 100000, TRUE ~ base_price),
      i1 = NULL, i2 = NULL)
```

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to make a date time column using lubridate, and then adding values to the max of that.

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
values <- c(100000,100000,200000)

## create datetime column with lubridate
mydat <- mydat %>% as_tibble  %>% 
    mutate(date = dmy(date),
                 hour = hm(paste0(hour,":00")),
                datetime = ymd_hms(paste(date, hour)))

## get the last datetime for each supplier and add values
to_bind <- mydat %>% group_by(supplier) %>% 
    slice_max(datetime) %>% 
    ungroup() %>% 
    mutate(added = values,
                 base_price = base_price + added) %>% 
    select(-added)

## bind_rows with new values 
mydat %>% group_by(supplier) %>% 
    filter(datetime !=max(datetime)) %>% 
    bind_rows(to_bind) %>% 
    arrange(supplier, datetime)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `split()` and `Map()`

```
do.call(rbind,
Map(function(add, dat){
  # subset variable to add to 
  tmp1 <- dat[, "base_price"]
  
  # add desired amount
  dat[, "base_price"][nrow(dat)] <- tmp1[nrow(dat)] + add

  # return
  dat
},
# here you can choose the number that is added for each supplier
c(1e5, 1e5, 2e5),  
split(mydat, mydat[, "supplier"])))

# yields

#        supplier       date hour weekday base_price
# 1       MyAgent 28.03.2021    3       0    1944.70
# 2       MyAgent 28.03.2021    4       0    1949.43
# 3       MyAgent 28.03.2021    5       0    1954.16
# 4       MyAgent 28.03.2021    6       0  101958.89
# 5            S7 25.03.2021    7       4    4595.20
# 6            S7 25.03.2021    8       4    3170.02
# 7            S7 25.03.2021    9       4    1744.84
# 8            S7 25.03.2021   10       4     319.65
# 9            S7 25.03.2021   11       4   98894.47
# 10 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    4       0       3.83
# 11 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    5       0       3.49
# 12 Travelfusion 28.03.2021    6       0  200003.15
```